# How to make navbar change color on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a transparent nav bar which on scroll is transparent. This means that if i were to scoll to a place that did not have a solid background color it would clash with other elements such as text. I would like to transtition into a different color to make it stand out more (including making the logo and a tags black) because at the moment it overlaps with text making it barely readable. How can i make it change color on scroll?

full code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

*, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -----------------------------Background------------------------------- */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -----------------------------Navigation------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Make the header */
.header{
  height: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

/* Set the logo */
.logo{
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  color: #fff;
}

/* Set the clickable nav to the right */
.menu{
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Transition and color of attribute tags */
.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Set color for hover */
menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.show-menu-btn{
  float: right;
}

.show-menu-btn i{
  line-height: 100px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
  color: #AEC6CF;
}

#chk{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1111;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --------------------------Responsive-Menu---------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
  .menu a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
  }
  .hide-menu-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
  }
  #chk:checked ~ .menu{
    right: 0;
  }

  .header {
    height: 90px;
  }

  .logo {
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .menu ul a {
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .show-menu-btn i, .hide-menu-btn i{
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .hide-menu-btn {
    color: #000000;
  }
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------Sections-------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Section for text */
.main {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Make text smaller and centered on desktop screen */
.main p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

/* Header Underline */
hr {
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #AEC6CF
}

/* Make text larger and on the left for mobile */
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .main p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg" id='home'></div>
<div class="header" id='pronav'>
  <div class='logo' id='logo'>
    <p style='font-size:35px;'>lunAr-creator</p>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#home" onclick="navbarFunc()">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="navbarFunc()">About</a>
    <a href="#projects" onclick="navbarFunc()">Projects</a>
    <a href="#useful_links" onclick="navbarFunc()">Useful Links</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="navbarFunc()">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main" id="about">
  <h2 style='margin-top: 90px;'>About Me</h2>
  <hr/>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  </p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <hr/>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link Background Color to Scroll Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032952/link-background-color-to-scroll-position)

Comment: not exactly because you would still be able to see the clash of text until you get to the point where it has finsihed the transition.Maybe a little something like this: https://codepen.io/jhiam/pen/woZaKZ but from transparent to a different color (such as white)

Comment: @lunAr-creator FYI, you could make things easier for yourself by using the native `header` and `nav` tags.. no need to create classes and ids for these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the parent element of the header and nav ***prenav*** and set the background color to change using a transition when the `window.pageYOffset` hits a certain threshold in a ***scroll*** event listener. Use another conditional to change it back if you scroll up to the fold again...

If you want to change the color of the font instead of the background-color change the `el.style.backgroundColor` to `el.style.color` and the transition from `logo.style.transition = 'background .5s ease-out'` to `logo.style.transition = 'color .5s ease-out'`.

```js
const logo = document.querySelector('#pronav')

const getOffset = () => {
  if(window.pageYOffset > 100){
     logo.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'
     logo.style.transition = 'background .5s ease-out'
     logo.style.boxShadow = '0px 1px 4px black'
  }
  if(window.pageYOffset < 100){
     logo.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
     logo.style.transition = 'background .5s ease-out'
     logo.style.boxShadow = 'none' 
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', getOffset)
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

*, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -----------------------------Background------------------------------- */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------*/


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* -----------------------------Navigation------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Make the header */
.header{
  height: 80px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

/* Set the logo */
.logo{
  line-height: 80px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  color: #fff;
}

.pronav {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transition: background .5s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 4px black;
}

/* Set the clickable nav to the right */
.menu{
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Transition and color of attribute tags */
.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Set color for hover */
menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.show-menu-btn{
  float: right;
}

.show-menu-btn i{
  line-height: 100px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
  color: #AEC6CF;
}

#chk{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1111;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* --------------------------Responsive-Menu---------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .show-menu-btn,.hide-menu-btn{
    display: block;
  }
  .menu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: 0.7s;
  }
  .menu a{
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    color: black;
  }
  .hide-menu-btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
  }
  #chk:checked ~ .menu{
    right: 0;
  }

  .header {
    height: 90px;
  }

  .logo {
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .menu ul a {
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .show-menu-btn i, .hide-menu-btn i{
    line-height: 90px;
  }

  .hide-menu-btn {
    color: #000000;
  }
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* ------------------------------Sections-------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Section for text */
.main {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/* Make text smaller and centered on desktop screen */
.main p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

/* Header Underline */
hr {
  width: 230px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #AEC6CF
}

/* Make text larger and on the left for mobile */
@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .main p {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet'>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="bg" id='home'></div>
<div class="header" id='pronav'>
  <div class='logo' id='logo'>
    <p style='font-size:35px; '>lunAr-creator</p>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu" id='navbar'>
    <a href="#home" onclick="navbarFunc()">Home</a>
    <a href="#about" onclick="navbarFunc()">About</a>
    <a href="#projects" onclick="navbarFunc()">Projects</a>
    <a href="#useful_links" onclick="navbarFunc()">Useful Links</a>
    <a href="#contact" onclick="navbarFunc()">Contact</a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
      <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
    </label>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="main" id="about">
  <h2 style='margin-top: 90px;'>About Me</h2>
  <hr/>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  </p>
</div>

<div class="main" id="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <hr/>
  <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec venenatis faucibus metus eu dignissim. Nunc eleifend non tellus a molestie. Sed eleifend porta diam, non varius risus laoreet id. Ut nisi purus, bibendum a vestibulum in, pulvinar a tellus. In mattis enim eu risus ullamcorper, quis semper est elementum. In a dapibus leo. Morbi elit elit, euismod in purus in, fermentum pellentesque diam. Praesent ligula diam, congue sit amet ullamcorper vel, vestibulum vitae magna. Suspendisse potenti. In nisi nibh, pretium id odio in, pellentesque porttitor orci. Duis sed imperdiet mauris. 
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very well explained answer and thanks for the examples :D